# После перезагрузки страницы скрипт работы переключателей перестает выполняться

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть группа переключателей, которые окрашиваются в темно-серый цвет при выборе переключателя `:check`.

Все работает хорошо до тех пор пока отправки формы на странице заполнена правильно, но, как только в ней допущена ошибка и страница перезагружается с уведомлением об ошибке, группа переключателей перестает окрашиваться в темно-серый цвет при выборе переключателя.

Как это можно исправить?

**Код:**

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let className = 'label-active';
  let $inputs_time = $('#order_time_field input[type=radio]');
  $inputs_time.change(function(ev) {
    $inputs_time.parent('label').removeClass(className);
    $(this).parent('label').addClass(className);
  });
});
```

```css
.form-row label.label-active {
 background-color: #e4e4e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-priority="20" class="form-row form-row-wide" id="order_time_field">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Время доставки</legend><label><input type="radio" name="order_time" value="Ближайшее"> Ближайшее</label><label><input type="radio" name="order_time" value="К определенному времени"> К определенному времени</label></fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: по идее, в консоли должна быть ошибка в момент, когда не работает окрашивание, посмотрите, что там.

Comment: @Максим Степанов неа, в консоли нет ошибок

Comment: приходит в голову только то, что при перезагрузке где-то переопределяется `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`

Answer (score 0):

Такое часто случается, если по какой-то причине на странице присутствует несколько элементов DOM c одинаковым id.  Т.к. вы делаете выборку элементов по id

```
$('#order_time_field input[type=radio]')
```

проверьте их уникальность. Лучше формировать селектор по классу.

А для полного ответа хотелось бы увидеть где-то полностью этот сценарий.

Comment: Не согласен с тем, что лучше по классу. Это подход называется "точно сработает", но при этом может приводить к ошибкам, которых не видно сразу. По классу лучше тогда, когда это обусловлено задачей, но не везде где попало.